# VB.NET Process Standart Output redirect does not work on OpenSSH SCP

Tags: vb.net, scp, system.diagnostics

Somehow Standart Output is not redirected when i use the OpenSSH SCP Executable with System.Diagnostics.Process

I'm working on managed Windows PC and have to send files to an SFTP Server which is password only protected. As i'm not able to install any other program or library im stuck with Windows's default OpenSSH Client which has no password argument. The PCs are behind a corporate Firewall which have no access to the internet. But thats what i'm stuck with.

My Approach is to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to launch the SCP command, listen for the Password prompt and then use `System.IO.StreamWriter` to send it.

while this does seem to work on test cases where i listened to `ipconfig` and sent input afterwards, i'm struggling with `scp`, `sftp` and other programms as the DefaultOutput does not seems to be redirected.

Simplified Code:

```vb
Private Dim Output = ""
Public Function CreateAndStartProcess(FileName As String, Optional Arguments As String = "")
  Dim targetProcess As New Process()
  targetProcess.StartInfo.FileName = FileName
  targetProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments
  targetProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
  targetProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
  targetProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
  targetProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
  
  targetProcess.Start()
  AddHandler targetProcess.OutputDataReceived, OutputHandler

  return targetProcess 
End Function

Sub OutputHandler(sender, e, process) //never gets called
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Output = Output & Environment.NewLine & e.Data
End Sub

Dim targetProcess = CreateAndStartProcess("C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\OpenSSH\\scp.exe", "C:\test.txt user@host:/test")
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) //just for simplification
Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = targetProcess.StandardInput
SW.WriteLine("password")
```

When i put a breakpoint into `OutputHandler`, it never gets called. After execution the `Output` String is empty

Is there anything i'm missing? when using ipconfig it works just fine.

[image: Screenshot of SCP Execution]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you got that to compile. You method signature for the output handler was wrong...

Based on your VB code it looks like you might be trying to recreate the C# example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=net-6.0

I don't have whatever host you are trying to connect to, so the OutputHandler when it fired for me was an empty string. However, the ErrorHandler I added in the code below had output from the process.

I'd recommend reading the doc I link above.
A couple of key points from their example code that I used to modify your code:

1. You have to call process.BeginOutputReadLine() to get the OutputHandler method to fire.
2. You need to call process.WaitForExit() or set process.EnableRaiseEvents = True and add an Exit event handler or you're never going to know when the process ends.
3. The output event handler only gets called when a newline (CR, LF, or CR+LF) are sent to the StandardOutput stream. It could be that line says 'Password:' is waiting for input on that line, so newline has been sent yet, and so Password: hasn't been sent to our OutputHandler. So instead of the OutputHandler method, you might need to tap into the StandardOutput stream directly to read without waiting for a newline.
4. You might want to add the ErrorHandler method (or something similar) in case you are getting an error message to the StandardError stream instead of the output stream.

   ```
    Sub Main()
        Dim targetProcess = CreateAndStartProcess("C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\OpenSSH\\scp.exe", "C:\test.txt user@host:/test")
        targetProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
        targetProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()

        Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = targetProcess.StandardInput
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) '//just For simplification
        SW.WriteLine("password")

        targetProcess.WaitForExit()

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Output) Then Console.WriteLine(Output)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorOutput) Then Console.WriteLine(ErrorOutput)
        targetProcess.WaitForExit()
        targetProcess.Close()

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Press any key to exit.")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Output As String = ""
    Private ErrorOutput As String = ""
    Public Function CreateAndStartProcess(FileName As String, Optional Arguments As String = "") As Process
        Dim targetProcess As New Process()
        targetProcess.StartInfo.FileName = FileName
        targetProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments
        targetProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        targetProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        targetProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        targetProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        targetProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False

        AddHandler targetProcess.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf ErrorHandler
        AddHandler targetProcess.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf OutputHandler
        targetProcess.Start()

        Return targetProcess
    End Function

    Sub OutputHandler(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs) '//never gets called
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Output = Output & Environment.NewLine & e.Data
    End Sub

    Sub ErrorHandler(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs) '//never gets called
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ErrorOutput = ErrorOutput & Environment.NewLine & e.Data
    End Sub
   ```

Comment: i will try to recreate that on monday, the handler signature was wrong, you're right. That was my mistake after simplifying the code for Stackoverflow.

your explanation makes totally sense. I will try that but for that great explanation you earned your bounty :)